# Flutter: calling a list using StreamProvider returns null before displaying data

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, flutter-provider

I'm trying to retrieve a list of objects from a Firebase collection using StreamProvider, and the objects are being retrieved, but for a split second the console throws an error with a red screen before the data is being rendered on the screen. This is the error being shown...

```
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length
```

This is what I have right now for code...

```
StreamProvider(create: (context) => _jobDb.getJobs(),),
```

```
Stream<List<Job>> getJobs() {
    return _api.streamDataCollection().map((snapshot) => snapshot.documents
        .map((document) => Job.fromJson(document.data))
        .toList());
  }
```

```
class ScrollableJobList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final jobs = Provider.of<List<Job>>(context);

    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        Job job = jobs[index];
        return JobListTile(
          jobDetails: job,
        );
      },
      itemCount: jobs.length,
    );
  }
}
```

So am I missing something here? I tried using the initial data parameter on the StreamProvider but that didn't work. Am I supposed to make something asynchronous or be using something like a FutureBuilder or returning something when there's no data but how would I implement that?

Comment: Have you tried checking if the data is empty or null then return the listview, otherwise a progress indicator ? Something like this: 
return (jobs.isEmpty || jobs == null) ? Center( child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : ListView.builder...

Comment: Ok thanks I tried the jobs.isEmpty but it crashed because isEmpty can't but called when it's null. The jobs == null worked though!

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `Consumer` widget in a couple with `StreamProvider`.

```dart
StreamProvider<List<Job>>(
  create: (context) => _jobDb.getJobs(),
  child: Consumer<List<Job>>(
    builder: (_, jobs, __) {
      return jobs == null ?
        CircularProgressIndicator() : 
        jobs.isEmpty ? 
          Text('No jobs') :
          ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              Job job = jobs[index];
              return JobListTile(
                jobDetails: job,
              );
            },
            itemCount: jobs.length,
          );
    }
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best tutorial I've seen so far, try to check it out.

[Flutter & Firebase App Tutorial #20 - Listing Brew Data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKM6_MTNGsI&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC&index=20)